# CSS How can I offset the first letter without negative margin?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm just mocking up a page for practice to see what I can find out on my own.

My goal is the offset the first letter of all paragraphs to the left with a different font, but it's giving me trouble.

The text ends up misaligned when using -1.0em margin. What is the best way to accomplish this? I'm fairly new to web development, so go easy on me!

```css
p::first-letter {
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
  font-size: 2.0em;
  margin-left: -1.0em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id="bodyWrap">

  <h1 id="header" class="underline">Placeholder</h1>

  <hr>
  <p>Some more placeholder text </p>

  <p>Some more placeholder text </p>

  <p>Some more placeholder text </p>

  <hr>

  <footer>Placeholder</footer>

</div>
```

The desired result would be to have the first letter in each paragraph nudged to the side without affecting the paragraph's placement.

Comment: What's the desired output and what does your HTML look like?

Comment: What do you mean by offset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use pseudo-element to have that letter as an element that you can style alone:

```css
p {
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

p::first-letter {
  opacity: 0;
}

p::before {
  content: attr(data-lettre);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<p data-lettre="L">
  Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume
</p>
```

And if you want to use `first-letter` you may adjust spacing like this.

*Since we deal with text you cannot have up/down movement in this case*

```css
p {
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

p::first-letter {
  margin-left:-1em;
  margin-right:1em; /*add the same as the margin-left*/
  font-size: 2.0em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved it for the most part. I've just got to do a little tweaking with font sizes to get it spaced out right for my mock up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [letter-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing):

```css
    p::first-letter {
      font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
      font-size: 2.0em;          
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="bodyWrap">
      <h1 id="header" class="underline">Placeholder</h1>
      <hr>
      <p>Some more placeholder text </p>
      <p>Some more placeholder text </p>
      <p>Some more placeholder text </p>
      <hr>
      <footer>Placeholder</footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: you have all the needed code in your answer so why not simply create a snippet and get rid of jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The `::first-letter` pseudo element applies to the first letter of an element, but it doesn't remove it from the normal flow, nor does it wrap the letter in a separate selectable element.

This means you can alter the typographical and a few other qualities ([list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter#Allowable_properties)) of the letter, but you can't move it without also moving the entire element.

If you want to offset the letter, create a nested container and use relative positioning. Then use the CSS offset properties (`top`, `bottom` `left` and `right`) to position the letter.

```css
p > span {
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
  font-size: 2.0em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  
}
```

```html
<p><span>P</span>ositioning only the first letter.</p>
```